# Exponential Kth Moment Derivation

Tags: moments, taylor-series

I have essentially a mathematical question, relating to deriving the formula for the kth moment of an exponential. I can't seem to work out how we get from the 2nd line to the 3rd line; i.e. the fraction to the expansion:
    \begin{align}%\label{}
  \nonumber M_X(s)&=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-s}\\
  \nonumber &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{s}{\lambda}}\\
\nonumber &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{s}{\lambda}\right)^k, \hspace{10pt} \textrm{for }\left|\frac{s}{\lambda}\right|<1\\
  \nonumber &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{\lambda^k} \frac{s^k}{k!}.
\end{align}
My maths is quite rusty so this is probably something simple but I would appreciate if someone could take a minute to help me out.
Cheers!

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is an infinite GP series which equals $1/(1-x)$ provided $|x|<1$. Pretty standard result. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39027/321264) answer on math.se is relevant.

Comment: @StubbornAtom - may as well re-post as an answer and get the points, since you did answer it!

Comment: This is an application of the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem).  Even if you don't know how the formula was derived, you can verify it by multiplying the sum by $1-s/\lambda$, verifying (since all terms but the first cancel out) that it produces $1.$  Indeed, I recall learning this from a high school algebra textbook that began with the sum--which is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)--and performed this multiplication to derive the equality.